# Tick the checkbox column in WPF datagrid through code

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have an ObservableCollection of items in which one of the property is bool.
When i set the itemsSource of the datagrid as the ObservableCollection, it auto-generates the column with checkbox column for the bool property.

I would like to know how we can tick the checkbox in code, lets say if we have the mark all option?

I tried updating the ObservableCollection records property value with true, but it doesnt help updating the UI.

Please help.

[EDIT: Below code works as suggested in the answer]
My Class is as follows

```
public class InvoiceDoc : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {   
        private bool _Selected;
        [DisplayName("Selected")]
        public bool Selected
        {
            get { return _Selected; }
            set { _Selected = value; this.OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }


        [DisplayName("Date")]                 
        public DateTime DocDate { get; set; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged !=null)
                this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

}
```

The datagrid is as follows

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgInvoices" Margin="32,110,32,59" AutoGeneratingColumn="dgInvoices_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

setting the ItemsSource is as follows

```
 docs = new ObservableCollection<InvoiceDoc>(); ;

 dgInvoices.ItemsSource = docs;
```

I am expecting the grid to auto check the check box once is set the value in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding to an ObservableCollection is only reactive if an Item is added or removed.

Your elements inside your Collection have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged so the UI recognises the changes

EDIT:

Lets say you have the following objects in your Collection:

```
public class MyClass {

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public bool IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

This class has now to be modified to the following:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged{
  private string _name;
  private bool _isActive;

  public string Name
  {
    get { return this._name; }
    set { this._name = value; this.OnPropertyChanged();}
  }

  public bool IsActive
  {
    get { return this._isActive; }
    set { this._isActive = value;
      this.OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

If there are any Errors, remove the CallerMemberNameAttribute and invoke the this.OnPropertyChanged(); with the Propertyname.

Comment: oh, yea. Add and Remove is working. do you have a sample for it?

Comment: But do we need to add handler to this event somewere?

Comment: No you dont have to. This is the magic how wpf + binding works ;)

Comment: Please provide some code so i can have a closer look

Comment: Oh, there was a minor error in my code, i resolved it. Thanks.